# Recursive Constructor Invocation when creating a Widget with form in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand the automatically code generated why QT when creating a QWidget with a Form.

This is the code generated by QT:

```
**********************************************************************
*  widget.h
**********************************************************************

#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
#endif // WIDGET_H

**********************************************************************
*  widget.cpp
**********************************************************************

#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

**********************************************************************
*  main.cpp
**********************************************************************

#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

My question is with this statement in the constructor:

ui(new Ui::Widget)

This is creating a new Widget when the constructor of class Widget is called. 
It's like recurssion isn't it? Why doesn`t it break?

Comment: Are you sure it's recursive? There's the `Ui` namespace that counteracts it.

Comment: What you are ignoring *is* a namespace's job, to reduce ambiguity, and why you **shouldn't** use `using namespace __namespace_name;`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recursive it s the instance of your ui_Widget.h Class since you need only one instance of your GUI at a time
The advantage of this approach is that the user interface object can be forward-declared, which means that we do not have to include the generated ui_Widget.h file in the header. The form can then be changed without recompiling the dependent source files. This is particularly important if the class is subject to binary compatibility restrictions.because as you can see the " #include "ui_widget.h"
is inside the cpp a not in the headers file

Answer (score 0):

NO. Because of namespaces there are two different classes with the same name:

Ui::Widget

and

Widget

Ui::Widget is the class for the form object.